# Powershell: get index of key in [Ordered] hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I know I can add to an [Ordered] hash table at a particular index, with

```
$ordered.Insert([Int], [String], [String])
```

and I can set the value at a certain index with

```
$ordered[[Int]] =
```

And that leads me to THINK that I should also be able to GET the index of a given key. It [seems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-7.0) that direct access isn't possible, as there in no `.IndexOf()` method. But I know I can get an array of the keys, and an array does have `.IndexOf()`, but that then returns another array, of `-1` for the non matches and `0` for the matches.
So

```
$ordered = [Ordered]@{
    'one' = 1
    'two' = 2
    'three' = 3
    'four' = 4
}
$ordered
$ordered.Keys.IndexOf('two')
```

produces

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
one                            1                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
two                            2                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
three                          3                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
four                           4                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-1
0
-1
-1
```

So now I need to get the index of that 0. So that doesn't seem to be the way to do it.
I also found [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/find-the-index-number-of-a-value-in-a-powershell-array/). And indeed this works.

```
[Array]::IndexOf($ordered.Keys,'three')
```

But it has me wondering, is there a way to make the previous approach work? `$ordered.Keys.IndexOf([String])` just seems like it should be viable, and I am just missing how to extract only the successful match. But perhaps not, and the static method is the way to go?

Comment: In PowerShell Core / .NET Core, `OrderedDictionaryKeyValueCollection` implements `IList` so, `$ordered[$ordered.Keys.IndexOf('two')]` works perfectly fine. In .NET Framework a bit more work is needed tho, I'm surprised you have a real use case for this. Why not explain what you're trying to accomplish as there is likely a better way to do it

Comment: It's a pretty edge case situation for sure. Related to my post earlier. I have an ordered hashtable of registry Uninstall keys, and some of those keys are actually extraneous Autodesk junk. Sometimes a redundant GUID key, sometimes a non GUID key, in both cases containing useless Uninstall info. So, I want to find the index of the correct item, and move (delete/add actually) the redundant key so it shows up in the log immediately after the correct one. As an aid in validating the results. It's... ugly. And FWIW, I am limited to PS 5.1.

Comment: Right I understand but, what is different doing (assuming this was possible for you in pwsh 5.1) `$ordered[$ordered.Keys.IndexOf('two')]` than doing just this `$ordered['two']` or `$ordered.ContainsKey('two')` for validation ? Maybe If you can add a reproducible example of your problem we may be able to help you find the best solution to the problem, I know what you have right now is a reproducible example but I think the solution you're looking for is reinventing the wheel in this case

Comment: The key is I need to find the index of 'two' so I can insert something at that index +1. For example, the correct Uninstall data for Autodesk Civil 3D 2023 is found in the `{AD211D5C-0BFF-3956-8998-C5C1F8FB5884}` key and some rubbish data is found in `{28B89EEF-6100-0409-2102-CF3F3A09B77D}`. In my log I want the correct log info `+ X64 {AD211D5C-0BFF-3956-8998-C5C1F8FB5884}: Autodesk Civil 3D 2023 - English (13.5.211.0) [ADSK GUID ODIS (ADSK GUID NULL)]` to be immediately followed by the bogus log item, despite the fact that it was actually processed first.

Comment: And I should say, the bogus item could be a GUID from earlier, or a GUID from later, or a non GUID key from later. Autodesk is ALL OVER the map as far as where info goes. So I process the keys in order, with conditionals that define the valid key and any key to skip, and if the skip has already been processed I can flag it, but if not I add the log item under its own path as the key, while also including the correct path. Then, when I later run across the path to skip, I can extract the correct path, find the index of the correct path, and insert the skip message right after. Fun. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Windows PowerShell*, **use `@(...)` to convert the `.Keys` collection to a regular array**, on which you can call `.IndexOf()`:

```bash
@($ordered.Keys).IndexOf('two')
```

Note: Unlike direct, key-based access to your ordered hashtable, `.IndexOf()` is case-*sensitive*.

---

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, the use of `@(...)` is **no longer necessary in *PowerShell (Core) 7.3+*** (.NET 7+), where the collection type contained in the `.Keys` property value itself implements the `IList` interface and therefore directly supports `.IndexOf()`.

---

Note:

- The above **also applies to accessing `.Keys` *by index***, e.g. `@($ordered.Keys)[0]` / `$ordered.Keys[0]`
- As of this writing, the 7.3+ / .NET 7+ improvement will only apply to [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary), the type that PowerShell's `[ordered] @{ ... }` literal syntax creates instances of, and not also to *other* ordered or sorted dictionary types;  [GitHub issue #63537](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63537) aims to change that.

---

As for **what happened in your attempt**:

Since in Windows PowerShell the `.Keys` collection itself has no `.IndexOf()` method, [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) was performed, resulting in `.IndexOf()` calls - as a *string* method - on *each key*.

Comment: good lord, by now I should be used to coercing things to proper arrays. It never occurred to me to check the type of the keys collection. I just assumed it was an array. Doh!

Comment: @Gordon, fortunately this isn't a concern anymore in PS Core. As for what happened without `@(...)` in WinPS: since the `.Keys` collection itself has no `.IndexOf()` method, [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) was performed, resulting in `.IndexOf()` call - as a _string_ method - on _each key_.

Comment: Yeah, someday I will remember that PowerShell will coerce things when I don't expect it, and have methods with the same name but totally different behavior. I am trying to refactor to use classes, which will help. But I need to be better at looking at  what type I am working with as soon as I have problems.

Comment: What worries me though is that I want to work in VS Code on Mac, because, well, Windows sucks. And VS Code performance on a Parallels VM also kinda sucks. But that means I will be developing in PS Core but production code runs in PS Windows. I need to make sure I can force VS Code to actually run everything in the PS 5.1 engine so that I don't get caught out by a whole new host of issues. :)

Comment: That sounds challenging, @Gordon. You'd have to find a linter that checks PowerShell code for 5.1 compatibility, and I'd be surprised if one existed.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [mklement0's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73921491/15339544) you could also extend the type itself adding a new [`PSScriptMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psscriptmethod?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) to find index of a Key. This can be accomplished with [`Update-TypeData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-typedata?view=powershell-7.2).

```
Update-TypeData -MemberType ScriptMethod -MemberName GetIndexOf -Value {
    param([object] $Key)

    return [array]::IndexOf($this.Keys, $Key)
} -TypeName System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary

$ordered.GetIndexOf('four') # => 3
```

Comment: I might not go this route for this particular issues, but good to know this is an option.